# Clean way to Template an HTML code block that only takes title/content parameters, where content may be large and littered with new-lines

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am using Accordion (jQuery) on my school webserver. Currently, my coding-scheme uses PHP/HTML/CSS/Javascript. I started noticing an opportunity for automation/templating when writing the entries for the Accordion modules. I write the following code:

```
<h3>Title</h3>
<div class="nobg">
  <p class="nobg">
    <!-- Entry text -->
  </p>
</div>
```

so I am looking for pointers for the best way to template that code based on the following needs:

- Adjustable parameters: Title, Content
- When making new modules with a large content 'parameter', the creation of that parameter should maintain readability.

Since I am already on PHP, I was thinking maybe some sort of template function:

```
<? php accordion_entry("Title", "Entry Text" ?>
```

But the text is usually a lot of HTML: like the following:

```
<a href="EnablerIIG/GSM0107_full.pdf">PDF</a>
  <p>
    The release date is 2007 but the pinout seems to check out (I did some small verifications with my PCB). Also, the reference documents are all valid!
  </p>
```

I would like to write that HTML myself in the designated spot where the module will eventually manifest as a whole. Perhaps even cooler would be something like this:

```
<accordion-entry title="Title">
    <a href="EnablerIIG/GSM0107_full.pdf">PDF</a>
    <p>
      The release date is 2007 but the pinout seems to check out (I did some small verifications with my PCB). Also, the reference documents are all valid!
    </p>
</accordion-entry>
```

I have no idea how to get started creating such a mechanism, or if it's too much trouble to bother.

Comment: use a variable to store the string and pass it in the function.

Comment: I edited to my post to reflect another desire of mine of the format of the template. Please take a look (see the XML-looking tags)

Comment: have you looked at AngularJS, Knockout, Handlebars, or Mustache?  These all allow you to do this built in, some easier/more lightweight than others.  I wll also provide a pure php answer, but I'd consider doing a bit of research on "data-binding" js libraries.

Comment: Brian, I just did a final edit on my post. Be sure to read it, it may change your answer!

Comment: ok.  Now it's even MORE like angularJs and Handlebars.  (both js libs). You also should take a look at smarty, which is a php templating language.  Basically, you're talking about templating and partials, and this is a component of MV* type applications (Model, View, whatever), and these solutions are typically part and parcel of templating libraries for both js and php.  I'll still show you in my answer how to do this natively though.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I also posted an easy-peezy lemon-squeezy solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my temporary solution, until someone comes along with something better! Please review! I am no PHP Expert!! :D

The PHP Function:

```
<?php

function accordionEntry($title, $entry)
{
    echo '<h3>' . $title . '</h3>';
    echo '<div class="nobg">';
    echo '  <p class="nobg">';
    echo $entry;                //  <!-- Entry text -->
    echo '  </p>';
    echo '</div>';
}

?>
```

The PHP function call:

```
<?php accordionEntry(
    "GSM0107IG001 - Integration Manual",

    '<a href="EnablerIIG/GSM0107_full.pdf">PDF</a>
    <p>
        The release date is 2007 but the pinout seems to check out (I did some small verifications with my PCB). Also, the reference documents are all valid!
    </p>');
?>
```

Comment: That certainly works, but where is your productivity gain?  You're moving into Object Oriented territory, and this is either a solution for a decorator, or a template object.

Comment: I have the feeling that if I showed my website as a whole. You would say "OUT WITH IT!" and redesign this awesome productive environment haha.

Comment: lol... maybe, but learning requires that you do it the long way first sometimes, so you understand the benefits of the better way.

Answer (score 0):

## Create a partial, and load your content into it along with settings

accordian.phtml  (just use .html if you want, doesn't really matter)

```
<accordion-entry title="<?php $title ?>">
   <?php $content ?>
</accordion-entry>
```

page.html

```
<div><?= renderPartial('accordian.phtml',array(
                                   'title'=>'GSM0107IG001 - Integration Manual',
                                   'content' => '<p>your html</p>'
                                    )); ?>
```

partial.php

```
function partial($partial, $settings){
     //will load html from indicated file, and merge passed settings and content into place before returning all $html
     // this allows the reuse of the 'partial()' function for other snippets

     $template = file_get_contents($partial);

     //$settings should be an array, and then your keys can be extracted as variables that match the $settings variables (such as $title) that exist in the .html partial file

     extract($settings);  //will assign any keys in your array, such as 'title' to php variables of the same name... so in this case $title, and $content

     echo $template;

}
```